# FORTRAN: A random number generator must be called many times? How to set the seed?

Tags: matlab, fortran, random

My random random number generator must be called many, unspecified, times:

```
    WRITE(*,*) Random_Number_routine([optional seed])
```

My random number generator has an optional integer argument, if present it uses this as the seed. If not present it calls system_clock(i) and uses i as the seed. So far so good. However if the Random_Number_routine is called too quickly, more than once a second, then system clock has not had a chance for the COUNT argument to change and the same value is returned. As an example consider an adaptation of the example given at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM_005fCLOCK.html

```
PROGRAM test_system_clock

    INTEGER :: count, count_rate, count_max

    DO i = 1, 100

        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count, count_rate, count_max)
        CALL srand(count) 
        WRITE(*,*) count, count_rate, count_max, rand()

    END DO

END PROGRAM test_system_clock
```

The output of test_system_clock is

```
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320589        1000  2147483647  0.640894175    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    
 5320590        1000  2147483647  0.640901804    

 4928363        1000  2147483647
```

The count argument only takes two values: 5320589 and 5320590. If this argument is used as the seed in srand i.e.

```
  Call srand(count)
```

Then the same seed is used and the same random numbers generated, which can be seen in the last column of the data. The only way around this is to generate $N$ random variables from a single seed, i.e.

```
CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count, count_rate, count_max)
Call srand(count) 

DO j = 1, n
    res(j) = rand()
END DO
```

However this assumes that one knows how many random variables are needed before the routine is called - which in this case I do not.

The only other train of through I've had is to use Fortran's save attribute and save the previous seed used - if its the first time the routine has been executed it uses SYSTEM_CLOCK to determine the seed, subsistent runs update the seed by some integer. However this does not produce random numbers as only the first in number in the sequence is used.

How do other software's get around this problem? How does a program like MATLAB do this? And how can I call the random number routine and guarantee a new random number?

UPDATE: In answer to francescalus comment: So in the first block of code shown I have called the routine 100 times, the last column in the table gives the random number generated for each call. There are only two values the random numbers take: 0.640894175 and 0.640901804. This appears to be  due to the fact that only two seed values are available (shown in column one). What I'm trying to determine is, given that I am calling the routine faster that the seed value changes, how can I get random numbers. i.e. if I call the routine 100 times then I expect 100 random values, not the same two values. Could it be a Fortran bug?

Comment: I think I now understand.  If I were using a PRNG I'd expect it to update the state suitable for the next call giving the next in a sequence.  That is, with something like `call my_prng(deviate, state)` I'd expect `state` to be `intent(inout)` (or being internally stored).  I wouldn't expect to be held responsible as a user to provide a distinct seed every single call (and this is more like a hash function than a PRNG) after the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You are reseeding your RNG every time through the loop.  My FORTRAN is *very* rusty, (FORTRAN IV anyone?) but I suspect you need to pull the srand() call out of your loop.  Something like:

```
PROGRAM test_system_clock

  INTEGER :: count, count_rate, count_max

  CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count, count_rate, count_max)
  CALL srand(count) 

  DO i = 1, 100

    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(count, count_rate, count_max)
    WRITE(*,*) count, count_rate, count_max, rand()

  END DO

END PROGRAM test_system_clock
```

In general, you should seed the RNG with srand() once at the start of your program, and then make repeated calls to rand() to generate the pseudo-random sequence without reseeding.

Answer (score 2):

The `rand()` method is a system call that is globally available, as is `srand`.  Call `srand` one time in the initialization phase of your program (either in your main, or a routine invoked first thing from main).  Then you can call `rand` as many times as you want from anywhere in the program to get pseudo-random values on demand without prior knowledge of how many will be needed.  The key concept here is that `srand` is used to **initialize** the state of the PRNG, and should only be invoked once per run of the program.

While you're at it, you should consider replacing `rand` with a better quality generator, it's pretty crappy.  The `rand` web page at gnu.org points you to [`random_number`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html) as a better alternative.

Comment: Implementation of "random_number` is implementation dependent and can be of various quality (actually it can just call `rand`), but at least in gfortran the implementation is a quite decent Marsaglia's KISS PRNG.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the info, I knew that for gfortran it was better than `rand` but didn't know details.